# I am trying to debug my Ruby project, but getting error "evaluation memory limit is ineffective mri < 2.0"

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, bdd, watir

[image]In my project we have used cucumber with bdd framework, when i try to debug it's not redirecting to step definition file, script terminating abruptly.

Comment: There isn't sufficient information in your question for anyone to answer it. Please expand your question with relevant information about, your project, how you are trying to debug, where you are putting the debug statement etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to test SAP application, in that we developed scripts using Ruby and also we have used cucumber with BDD, here I am trying to debug scenario and the first step Given I have access to SAP application, i put debug point in step definition file exactly for the Given implementation. But it is exiting abruptly and giving the error mentioned above. I have added error screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: I can't help you with answer. The question is a bit better, but I think it needs more. You should show the debug statement in context. The error is suggesting this is a JRuby issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks diabolist, now The first issue "evaluation memory.." solved and the second statement in screen shot "Fast debugger(ruby-debug..)" getting, any idea on this ?